# What are the elemental weaknesses?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

Pretty straightforward question here. Which elements are super-effective against which other elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elemental weaknesses are fairly straightforward. The strength/weakness pattern doesn't seem to involve all of the elements, but rather just pairs.

- **Fire** (red) does more damage to **Water** (blue) enemies and vice versa
- **Earth** (yellow) does more damage to **Wind** (green) enemies and vice versa.

Remember, the color of the targeting reticule determines what element the enemy is associated with.